# next production Build failed because of webpack/babel transpile issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, next.js

I am getting following error while creating production build after setup jest + enzyme using reference of https://levelup.gitconnected.com/configuring-jest-for-next-js-react-and-babel-from-scratch-bb3b7751329b. 
It's working fine in dev mode. Any solution. It seems to be a transpile issue.

````
vijdadhi$ yarn build
yarn run v1.22.4
$ next build
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `yarn upgrade`
> Using external babel configuration
> Location: ".../repo/babel.config.js"
Creating an optimized production build  

Failed to compile.

./src/pages/404.js
SyntaxError: .../src/pages/404.js: Unexpected token (4:4)
```
  2 | export default function Custom404() {
  3 |   return (
> 4 |     <h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
    |     ^
  5 |   );
  6 | }
  7 | 
```
> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (.../node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:10:900)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
vijdadhi$
````

Error logs

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.2.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v14.2.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~prebuild: nextjs-docker@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: nextjs-docker@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/vijdadhi/Public/personal/projects/Lloyds/dev/repo/ep-mgf-ui-dashbaord/node_modules/.bin:/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/bin:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vijdadhi/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: CWD: /Users/vijdadhi/Public/personal/projects/Lloyds/dev/repo/ep-mgf-ui-dashbaord
10 silly lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'next build' ]
11 silly lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle nextjs-docker@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: nextjs-docker@1.0.0 build: `next build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid nextjs-docker@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/vijdadhi/Public/personal/projects/Lloyds/dev/repo/ep-mgf-ui-dashbaord
16 verbose Darwin 18.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/14.2.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.2.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error nextjs-docker@1.0.0 build: `next build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the nextjs-docker@1.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

1 .bablerc file is

```
{
  "presets": [
    "next/babel",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "styled-components",
      {
        "ssr": true,
        "displayName": true,
        "preprocess": false
      }
    ]
  ],
}
```

2. babel.config.js file is

```
module.exports = {
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/react",
        "next/babel"
      ]
    },
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "next/babel"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

3. next.config.js file is

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [],
  {

    webpack: (config, {dev, isServer}) => {
       if (isServer) {
          return config;
       }
       var isProduction = config.mode === 'production';
       if(!isProduction) {
        config.optimization.minimize = false;
        config.optimization.minimizer = [];
       }
       return config
    }
 }
);
```

Comment: could you please share your jest.config.js and .babelrc?

Comment: @VijayD did you manage to fix it successfully?

Comment: @VijayD how did you resolve this?